# CSS Mobile-compatible Theme for Drupal?

Tags: 7, theming

Are there any CSS Mobile-compatible Theme for Drupal?

Example of a CSS mobile-compatible site: http://framelessgrid.com/

Comment: Found the solution via `Kenn_VM` on IRC.

The keyword I need to search for in the Drupal themes repository is **responsive**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Responsive", as mentioned in your comment, is indeed the buzzword. On a small scale, I have had success using [Sky](http://drupal.org/project/sky) to create a mobile friendly site.

Comment: Thanks, but I am a little skeptical at those HTML5+CSS3 themes.. created a separate question for addressing this skepticism: [Should I steer clear of CSS3 and HTML5?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/128245/)